# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method from salesforce to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, apex, sfdc

I am creating signature for getting file from amazon S3 from salesforce. I am getting below error

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method. I am using below code

```
Blob signatureBlob = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf('MY Secrate Code') ,Blob.valueOf(('GET\n\n\n'+Datetime.now().addminutes(2).getTime()/1000+'\n/bucketname/sfaccounts/BillPayment.pdf')));
String signatureString = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(signatureBlob);
signatureString  = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signatureString , 'UTF-8');
PageReference pg = new PageReference('https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/sfaccounts/BillPayment.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=accessID&Expires='+Datetime.now().addminutes(2).getTime()/1000+'&Signature=' + signatureString);
return pg;
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: If your intention is to use the identical Expires time value in two places then you should call `Datetime.now().addminutes(2).getTime()/1000`once, assign its value to a variable, and then use that variable twice.

Comment: @jarmod i am used expire time in a variable but it giving same response

Comment: String expTime = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().addminutes(2).getTime()/1000);
    Blob signatureBlob = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf('MYSECRETCODE') ,Blob.valueOf(('GET\n\n\n'+expTime+'\n/bucketName/sfaccounts/BillPayment.pdf')));
    String signString = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(signatureBlob);
    signString  = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signString , 'UTF-8');
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/sfaccounts/BillPayment.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY&Expires='+expTime+'&Signature=' + signString);

using above code but same response

Comment: The docs for Apex Crypto.generateMac() suggest that the parameters are, in order: algorithmName, input, privateKey. You seem to be supplying: algorithmName, privateKey, input.